# Create `PeriodIndex` from given list of start/end dates

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

To aggregate a DataFrame into a pivot table, I would like to create a `PeriodIndex`. Under normal circumstances, I would call `index = pd.DatetimeIndex(column).to_period('M')`). However, in my case the periods are already given by a list of start/end datetimes (`[{'start': '2020-01-01', 'end': '2020-02-01'}, {'start': '2020-02-01', 'end': '2020-03-01'}, ... ]`).

How would I go about turning this list into a `PeriodIndex` using Pandas (without making assumptions about the frequency)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need specify month period, because if use difference got:

```
L = [{'start': '2020-01-01', 'end': '2020-02-01'}, 
     {'start': '2020-02-01', 'end': '2020-03-01'}]

f = pd.Period(L[0]['end']) - pd.Period(L[0]['start'])
p = pd.PeriodIndex([x['start'] for x in L], freq=f)

print (p)
PeriodIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01'], dtype='period[31D]', freq='31D')
```

---

```
p = pd.PeriodIndex([x['start'] for x in L], freq='m')
print (p)
PeriodIndex(['2020-01', '2020-02'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

EDIT: If use [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) is possible create period for each start and end separately, then ouput is list of `PeriodIndex`:

```
p = [pd.period_range(x['start'], x['end'], freq='m') for x in L]
print (p)
[PeriodIndex(['2020-01', '2020-02'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M'),
 PeriodIndex(['2020-02', '2020-03'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')]
```

Better ouput is flatten them:

```
p = [y for x in L for y in pd.period_range(x['start'], x['end'], freq='m')]
print (p)
[Period('2020-01', 'M'), Period('2020-02', 'M'),
 Period('2020-02', 'M'), Period('2020-03', 'M')]
```

Then is possible convert to `PeriodIndex` - there are duplicates:

```
p = pd.PeriodIndex([y for x in L for y in pd.period_range(x['start'], x['end'], freq='m')])
print (p)
PeriodIndex(['2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-03'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

So next step for unique values:

```
p = pd.PeriodIndex([y for x in L for y in pd.period_range(x['start'], x['end'], freq='m')]).unique()
print (p)
PeriodIndex(['2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-03'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

EDIT1:

```
p = [pd.period_range(x['start'], x['end'], freq='m') for x in L]
print (p)
[PeriodIndex(['2020-01', '2020-02'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M'), 
 PeriodIndex(['2020-02', '2020-03'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M'),
 PeriodIndex(['2020-03', '2020-04', '2020-05', '2020-06'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')]
```

Comment: Nice, can the periods be nonequidistant?

Comment: @orange - Not sure if understand, can you explain more?

Comment: Would it be possible to create a `PeriodIndex` with periods that have different time spans, for instance `[{'start': '2020-01-01', 'end': '2020-02-01'}, {'start': '2020-02-01', 'end': '2020-04-01'}, ... ]`?

Comment: @orange - I think you ned `EDIT`, can you check it?

Comment: It doesn't quite work. Check out this example: `L = [{'start': '2020-01-01', 'end': '2020-02-01'}, {'start': '2020-02-01', 'end': '2020-03-01'}, {'start': '2020-03-01', 'end': '2020-06-01'}]`. The last period is 3 months long, but `[y for x in L for y in pd.period_range(x['start'], x['end'], freq='m')][-1].start_time` gives `Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00')`.

Comment: @orange - What should be ouput from `L = [{'start': '2020-01-01', 'end': '2020-02-01'}, {'start': '2020-02-01', 'end': '2020-03-01'}, {'start': '2020-03-01', 'end': '2020-06-01'}]`  ?

Comment: The last period should be 3 months long (2020-03-01...2020-06-01) and the other two periods should be 1 month each.

Comment: @orange - Close id create list of periodindex, added to `EDIT1`. Or need something else?

Comment: With the given `L` (3 items), `EDIT1` produces 3 `PeriodIndex` objects. What I need is 1 `PeriodIndex` with 3 `Period` objects for which the last period starts 2020-03-01 and ends on 2020-06-01 (exclusive).

Comment: @orange - So it means is possible get first start and last end and pass to `pd.period_range` with frequancy month ?

Comment: I don't want to _calculate_ the `PeriodIndex`. The periods are already given (by start/end dates). These periods somehow need to be used to create the `PeriodIndex`.

Comment: Maybe it's not possible to do that. `pd.PeriodIndex([pd.Period('2020-01-01', freq='M'), pd.Period('2020-01-02', freq='2M')])` gives an exception: `pandas._libs.tslibs.period.IncompatibleFrequency: Input has different freq=2M from PeriodIndex(freq=M)`

Comment: @orange - Yes, I got it. It is impossible, need same frequency